# PHP: Assign variable and test against it in same if statement?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I want to do this:

```
if ($field = myFunction($node, 'field') && $field['value']) {
  //do something with $field
}
```

PHPStorm warns that $field is undefined after the && even though it was just set.  Is this just PHPStorm being flaky or is there some reason this actually shouldn't work?

Comment: It doesn't warn me, which version are you using ?

Comment: @Guns it's not a solution, read carefully

Comment: @Guns actually he want to assign a variable in the left statement and compare in the right one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's operator precedence. Just look at http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

It should be:

```
if (($field = myFunction($node, 'field')) && $field['value']) {
  //do something with $field
}
```

to work as you expected. In this case PhpStorm  doesn't warn

*Such cases show that it's better always use parentheses if you are not 100% sure about operation order. Imagine what could happen if PhpStorm doesn't warn you in this case and in your tests it was working as expected.*

Comment: You linked the PL version of the documentation, it contains non-english words (see *Przykład #1 Associativity*). I suggest you to link the english page.